# Checking url exists with jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This has me totally confused.  I'm trying to run through a series of Youtube ids to check if the videos still exist.

I have all the ids in an array and want to check the gdata api to see if I get XML results or a Video not found 404 message.

I found a function on SO to check each id and add a row to a table.

```
var ytarray = ARRAY OF YOUTUBE IDs
var yttitles = ARRAY OF MATCHING TITLES FOR THE VIDS
var urlExists = function(url, callback){
$.ajax({
            type: 'HEAD',
            url: url,
            success: function() {
                callback(true);
            },
            error: function() {
                callback(false);
            }            
        });

    }
    var length = ytarray.length,
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    urlExists('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'ytarray[i], function(success) {
        if (success) {
              $('#rows').append('<tr><td>'+yttitles[i]+'</td><td>'+ytarray[i]+'</td><td style="color: green">Found</td></tr>');
        } else {
              $('#rows').append('<tr><td>'+yttitles[i]+'</td><td>'+ytarray[i]+'</td><td style="color: red">Not Found</td></tr>');
        }
    });
    };
});
});
```

The table fills out but all of the rows contain the information for the last video not each one as it goes through the loop.

Testing with alerts it seems the table doesn't get filled out until all the for loops have completed.

I wonder if this is something to do with me not handling the asynchronous nature of AJAX correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ytarray   = ["ARRAY OF YOUTUBE IDs"],
    yttitles  = ["ARRAY OF MATCHING TITLES FOR THE VIDS"],
    urlExists = function(url){
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'HEAD',
            url : url
        });
    },
    output = function(state, i) {
        var tr  = $('<tr />'),
            td1 = $('<td />', {text : yttitles[i]}),
            td2 = $('<td />', {text : ytarray[i]}),
            td3 = $('<td />', {text : state ? 'Found' : 'Not found', 
                               style: state ? 'color: green' : 'color:red'});

        $('#rows').append( tr.append(td1, td2, td3) );
    },
    length = ytarray.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    (function(k) {
        urlExists('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + ytarray[k])
           .done(function() {
             output(true, k);
           }).fail(function() {
                output(false, k);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Took some time to figure it out, but you'll need some closures, and a different way of handling the asynchronous behaviour.

Comment: This works like a dream!  I don't think I'd have worked this out for myself.  Any explanation of what you did here would be really useful.

Comment: Just gave it a little structure, adding a clousure in the loop, and returned the deferred promise from the ajax function to work with it the way it was intended.

Answer (score 2):

Try to preserve i. callbacks will be called after ajax response till then for loop is finished so value of i will be equal to length.

```
   for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          (function(i){
            urlExists('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'ytarray[i], function(success) {
                if (success) {
                      $('#rows').append('<tr><td>'+yttitles[i]+'</td><td>'+ytarray[i]+'</td><td style="color: green">Found</td></tr>');
                } else {
                      $('#rows').append('<tr><td>'+yttitles[i]+'</td><td>'+ytarray[i]+'</td><td style="color: red">Not Found</td></tr>');
                }
            });
        })(i)
     }
```

Comment: I get "unexpected identifier".  Does this refer to i?

Comment: @DaveR can't say, just put your code inside a anonymous function

Answer (score 2):

I was puzzled by how to perform URL validation in a synchronous manner.
I then happen to come across YQL, played with it for a while, and composed this:

```
  function isValidURL(url) {
    var encodedURL = encodeURIComponent(url);
    var isValid = false;

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" + encodedURL + "%22&format=json",
      type: "get",
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        isValid = data.query.results != null;
      },
      error: function(){
        isValid = false;
      }
    });

    return isValid;
  }
```

The usage is straight forward:

```
var isValid = isValidURL("http://www.wix.com");
alert(isValid ? "Valid URL!!!" : "Damn...");
```

Hope this can help whoever tried verifying a URL, synchronously.